# Laravel Filament crop Image before upload

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-filament

When I call the method FileUpload::make('image')->imageCropAspectRatio('1:1') on Filament, the image is cropped only after the upload. However, I would like the user to be able to choose which area is cropped, so like when using Cropper.js for example.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what have you already tried? please edit this question and add pieces of code you already tried

Comment: https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-image-cropper-components-by-cropperjs/ Here is what youre looking for